# Get instance of component on active route in Angular2's router?

Tags: angular, components, angular2-routing

I know that `ActivatedRouteSnapshot.component` in Angular2 contains the reference/class to the activated route if I call `Router.routerState.snapshot` but how to get for the component class the current (or minimal: one created) instance for it?

`Injector.get(..)` does not return instances of components and creating a new instance of a component does also not help (me).

Comment: can you elaborate a bit what you're doing? where do you want to get the reference to the component class? what component?

Comment: The component has (depending on the environment) sometimes a property (`showFooter`) set to `true` and sometimes to `false` -  it depends on the data it receives from a REST endpoint. If it is false the App component which contains the `<router-outlet ...>` and also the `<app-footer ...>` should hide or show the footer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
<router-outlet
  (activate)='onActivate($event)'
  (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
```

where `$event` is the component instance and for example assign it to a service to make it available globally.

See also https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

You can also create a custom `<router-outlet>` component that does that automatically.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it with the ActivateRoute.

For example, if you have the Injector service:

```
const activatedRoute: ActivateRoute = this.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
```

then

```
component reference: this.injector.get(activatedRoute.component);
```

However, this only works if the injector instance you use has reference to that component itself.

In my example, this can be used to find the ViewComponent from a child of that view.

```
|- ViewComponent
  |- ChildComponent
    |- ChildComponent
      ... injector here -> using the code above, gets the ViewComponent' instance 
  |- ChildComponent
```

This may not work in your instance, however, hopefully this may help someone.