# How to get component name from active router link in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, components, angular-routing

I want to get the name of component which is active by router link in header layout. and then make a check based on the component name active.
If there is a way, please help me out sort of this situation.
currently I m fetching the router link address in **ngOnInit** method

```
this.router.url
```

I also want the component name that is linked to active router link, because in some cases component names and url segments are not matched in my application

Comment: Please add some more details and some code on what you have tried.

Comment: updated my query,

Comment: what are routes that don't get loaded as you said. Can you list an example. This might be because of order of routes defined.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use:

   //  router-outlet>
         (activate)='onActivate($event)'
         (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'>

where $event is the component instance. Taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431729/6528560

2. You should add data with component name to each route definition, and then just read it in ActivatedRoute

   public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
         console.log(route.snapshot.data['name']);
       }

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863833/6528560

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will helps you.

```
this.route.routeConfig.component.name
```

It will return component name.

Comment: This does not return the expected component when using a production build, as the component name has been minified if --optimization = true flag set.